# g++ -I does not work in order specified

Tags: c++, linux, g++, header-files

I am running g++ on a Linux system where my stable header files exist in a read-only directory /inc and the one(s) I am working on are in /inctest.
As a result of this, the same filename can exist in both directories. I want to be able to keep it this way, so that I always include any headers present in /inctest before any are included from /inc.

The problem I am having is that at different times it seems to arbitrarily take from either of those directories, rather than always the same one first.

That is, I run g++ -I/inctest -I/inc a.cpp b.cpp ...

and sometimes I get the one from /inc, other times I get the one from /inctest.

Is the order that my -I parameters are specified irrelevant? The man page for g++ says "Order does matter when you use several options of the same kind".

Is there some other way I can guarantee always including headers from one directory before their same named counterpart in another directory? I still need to include both, as /inc contains all of the headers that I am not currently working on. Renaming the ones I am working on is not helpful because then I need to change all of my #includes...

Edit: I dug a little deeper and noticed that a header in /inc is including another header that exists in both /inc and /inctest. I copied this header temporarily to /inctest and sure enough, it now included the correct one. Is this a bug or proper behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact locations of headers isn't specified by the standard and generally compilers are somewhat lax on documenting what is being used. The `-I` flags are generally used for headers not found local to the file including something. However, when including a file another header, the file chosen typically depends on how files are being included:

- When using `#include <xxx>` in a header, the `-I` flags are observed.
- When using `#include "xxx"` in a header, the file is first looked up in the directory where the file with the `#include` directive is located.

The problem is, of course, that strictly speaking the form `<xxx>` is reserved to standard library use.

Comment: gcc threats `#include <xxx>` and `#include "xxx"` as documented here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

Comment: The key part of this answer for me was "the directory where the file with the #include directive is located." I was mistakenly assuming that the directory of my .cpp file with the original #include would be the same starting path for any #includes nested within it, which is not true.